How to call the destructor on a Lua object twice to catch double free?
I need to write a test that diagnoses double free for a Lua object created using ffi.new.
As a result, you need to call collectgarbage() twice, after which a double free situation should occur.
I wrote this example:
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef[[
typedef struct {
  int x;
} my_struct;
]]

local obj = ffi.new("my_struct", {10})
obj = ffi.gc(obj, function (o)
    print(123)
end)

obj = nil
collectgarbage("collect")
collectgarbage("collect")

but the destructor of this object is called only 1 time

Why do you expect a double free to occur here? The first call to collectgarbage should free the object. After that, it's freed; GC doesn't care about it anymore. The second call to collectgarbage hence does nothing. I'm not sure how you expect to achieve a double free in a garbage-collected language.

It is impossible to invoke a double free for automatically managed memory in LuaJIT (that is, created with ffi.new).
But you can do it for manually managed memory:
local ffi = require"ffi"
ffi.cdef[[
   typedef struct {
      int x;
   } my_struct;
   void* malloc(size_t);
   void free(void*);
]]

local function my_free(o)
   print(123)
   ffi.C.free(o)
end

local obj = ffi.gc(
   ffi.cast("my_struct*", ffi.C.malloc(ffi.sizeof("my_struct"))), 
   my_free
)
obj.x = 10

-- first free
my_free(obj)

-- second free
obj = nil
collectgarbage("collect")
collectgarbage("collect")

P.S.
BTW, huge blocks of memory are recommended to allocate as manually managed (instead of using ffi.new)
